# Print output using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-libxml

```
my $doc = $parser->parse_string( $res->content );
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement;
my @objects = $root->getElementsByTagName('OBJECT');

foreach my $object ( @objects ){
my $name = $object->firstChild;
print "OBJECT = " . $name . "\n";}


OUTPUT is:
OBJECT = XML::LibXML::Text=SCALAR(0x262e170)
OBJECT = XML::LibXML::Text=SCALAR(0x2ee4b00)
OBJECT = XML::LibXML::Text=SCALAR(0x262e170)
OBJECT = XML::LibXML::Text=SCALAR(0x2ee4b00)
```

Can anyone please explain why print prints the `$name` attribute values like this? Why does it print normal when I use the function `getAttribute` with virtually he same code?

Comment: Can you show the XML? What version of `XML::LibXML` do you run?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for a certain child element but have overlooked that there can be child text nodes with white space as well. So please show an XML input sample and explain which data you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAttribute` returns an attribute, while `firstChild` returns a text node, element, processing instruction, or a comment.

What you see is a normal Perl way of printing an object: it prints its class and address. Your version of [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) seems to be a bit antique, recent versions [overload](http://p3rl.org/overload) the stringification and the code produces the actual text node.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( string => << '__XML__');
<root>
    <OBJECT name="o1">hello</OBJECT>
</root>
__XML__

my @objects = $doc->getElementsByTagName('OBJECT');

for my $object (@objects) {
    print 'OBJECT = ', $object->firstChild, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
OBJECT = hello
```

In the old versions, one needed to call the `nodeValue` or `data` method.

```
print 'OBJECT = ', $object->firstChild->data, "\n";
```